# How to write setup.py to include a specific git repo as a dependency

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

My package has a dependency to a another git repo. My current setup.py file is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name='myapp', 
  url='git@ssh.xxxxx/dummy/myapp.git',
  packages=find_packages(), 
  install_requires = [
     'base @ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxx/dummy/base.git'
  ]
)
```

When I run the command "pip3 install . --user" to execute the setup.py file a base module is installed at userbase/lib/python3.6/site-packages, but this modul is not my base module.
The first line in the console after running the pip3 install command is

```
Collecting base@ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxx/dummy/base.git (from myapp==0.0.0)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/e5/464fcdb2cdbafc65f0b2da261dda861fa51d80e1a4985a2bb00ced080549/base-1.0.4.tar.gz"
Installing collected packages: base, myapp
```

It seems to me that pip3 is installing another base module, because the download path is not my git path. After that, the base folder in site-packages includes among other files a "taobao.py" and "seo.py" file.

Is there an option that pip3 is installing my base and not another base module?

I'm using pip 19.03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `'base @ git+ssh://git@ssh.xxxx/dummy/base.git'` is supported by [`pip` 19.1+](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers):

> Since version 19.1, pip also supports [direct references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references) like so:
>
> ```
> SomeProject @ file:///somewhere/...
> ```